# Decoding NSData Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to decode the following result.

Variable: `mifareTag.identifier` that is NSData (Identifier of Nfc Tag)

Printing it as NSData I got a response of: `7 bytes`

Printing it as `mifareTag.identifier as Data` I got `{length = 7, bytes = 0x047233d2386680}`

I have to decode it and save the variable `bytes`

How can I do that?

Comment: Data can be anything. Do you know what is the expected result for `0x047233d2386680`? What each byte means?

Comment: Yes, 0x047233d2386680 is the serial code of Nfc Tag, then it should be 04:72:33:D2:38:66:80

Comment: You can easily convert the bytes to hexa string. What do you need? Just a string representation?

Comment: Yes, I need that the 'bytes' is saved into a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast your NSData to Data and map the bytes to hexa string as follow:

```
let code = (mifareTag.identifier as Data).map { 
    .init(format: "%02X:", $0)    // or "%02x:" for lowercase letters
}
.joined()
.dropLast()

print("code:", code)
```

---

This will print

> code: 04:72:33:D2:38:66:80

---

If you need to save string you can get its data as follow:

```
let codeData = Data(code.utf8)
```